# Why this Java lambda expression parameter has an error?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-programming

This is an aritmetic expression evaluator that uses the interpreter GOF pattern, BinaryOp is a non terminal expression.

```
public class BinaryOP<T> implements Expression<T> {

    private Expression<T> e1;
    private Expression<T> e2;
    private BiFunction<Expression<T>, Expression<T>, T> f;

    public BinaryOp(Expression<T> e1, Expression<T> e2, 
            BiFunction<Expression<T>, Expression<T>, T> f){
        this.e1 = e1; this.e2 = e2; this.f = f;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T interpret(IContext context){
        return (T)f.apply(e1, e2);
    }
}
```

And variable is the terminal expression.

```
public class Variable<T> implements Expression<T> {     
    private T v;

    public Variable(T v){
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T interpret(IContext context){
        return (T)context.recognize(v);
    }
}
```

When defining the BiFunction sum I get an error when using the lambda, an error on its parameters, if a and b are of type expression and the result returns an integer ¿Why is this error?.

```
public class AritmeticInterpreter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    IContext<Integer> ctxArimetic = value -> value;

    BiFunction<Expression<Integer>, Expression<Integer>, Integer> sum
    //Error = incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression                                       
                = (a, b, result) -> {
                return (Integer)a.interpret(ctxArimetic) + (Integer)b.interpret(ctxArimetic);
           };
    }
}
```

What is causing this error, has to be the return type another expression?
if I change the interpret method return type to expression, I wouldn't be able to sum two expressions a and b like this:

```
(a, b) -> a + b
```

because they are not Integers.

and well, this no part of the title but, ¿can I get rid of casting interpret on method? I know that java compiler erases the generic type but, ¿is there a way?

Update:

Here is the Expression interface.

```
public interface Expression<T> {

     public <T> T interpret(IContext context);

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `Expression`?  I suggest using your IDE to refactor the code as an anonymous class, fix the code so it compiles and refactor it back.

Comment: For your last question: don't use raw types. e1 and e2 should be of type Expression<T>, not Expression. For the error: a BiFunction takes two arguments, and returns a result. Your lambda takes 3 arguments: a, b and result.

Comment: @JB Nizet  Thanks, I could fix the error using just a and b on the lambda, but for the last question I change e1 and e2 to be Expression<T> and I still have to cast.

Comment: `public <T> T interpret(IContext context){` should be `public T interpret(IContext context){`.

Comment: Yes, it works I don't have to cast. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to JB Nizet comment and this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/BiFunction/index.htm) I found that I just have to use a and b as arguments in the lambda.

Here is the correct code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    IContext<Integer> ctxArimetic = value -> value;     

    BiFunction<Expression<Integer>, Expression<Integer>, Integer> sum
            = (a, b) -> {
        return a.interpret(ctxArimetic) + b.interpret(ctxArimetic);
    };

}
```

and for the last question.

on BinaryOP class i make this change:

```
@Override
public T interpret(IContext<T> context){
        return f.apply(e1, e2);
}
```

and on the Expression Interface:

```
public interface Expression<T> {

       public T interpret(IContext<T> context);

}
```

This error was because I parametrized the interpret method, and this allows the method to return any object. I remember that the compiler output the error "T#2 is different from type T#1" T#2 was the generic parameter <T> on interpret method and T#1 was the generic type on the class BinaryOp<T>.

I didn't Know how to use lambdas and generics correctly.

Update: Fix some errors, I changed

```
public T interpret(IContext context);
```

To

```
public T interpret(IContext<T> context);
```

Comment: Yeah, when testing my code yesterday i have to fix some errors.